# Why wont my .NET 3.5 app run on fresh installation of windows7?

Tags: .net, windows-7

In `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework` i see v3.0 and v3.5. I found that path in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\InstallRoot` which also has that path.

In `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` i see versions from 1 to 3.5

My app was built in msvs2010rc1 targeting 3.5. In fact in my project files i see v3.5.

So whats with this? Why cant i run it?

-edit- The application crashes on double click. With no exception dialog.

Ok i see the problem. Sorry guys :$. I hope this post serves as a reference to someone else. I completely forgot that my app uses SDL.NET and i am use to C++ telling me i have forgotten a DLL.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Could you give some more details about what happens you you *attempt* to run the app?  What makes you think it's a framework version issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i see the problem. Sorry guys :$. I hope this post serves as a reference to someone else. I completely forgot that my app uses SDL.NET and i am use to C++ telling me i have forgotten a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch exception with AppDomain.UnhandledException and log the StaccTrace it will make things more clear.

Comment: How do i catch the exception? I dont have visual studios installed since its a fresh machine.

Comment: So you need to edit your code somewhere else and them copy the new application to the machine on which you have a problem and see the exception.